# ¿Porqué tengo este problema con TableView y iPhone 6/6s Plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableviewcontroller

Tengo el siguiente código que debería presentar un TableView con el Background con efecto Blurred.

```
LoginTableViewController * contributeViewController = [[LoginTableViewController alloc] init];

[self presentViewController:[UIHelpers blurredViewController:contributeViewController withFrame:contributeViewController.view.frame andBlurEffectStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight] animated:YES completion:nil];
```

pero en el iPhone 6 y 6s Plus la tabla se puede mover como una scroll view de lado a lado, no esta fija.

Tambien intente sin el efecto blur, directamente asi:

```
[self presentViewController:contributeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

pero sigo con el mismo resultado y la TableView moviéndose de lado a lado.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Se require más código de referencia para darte una respuesta puntual, pero se puede deducir que el error está en tu método `UIHelpers` que supongo debe devolver un `UIViewController` a `presentViewController`, ya que le estas pasando el frame del mismo `contributeViewController` que acabas de crear, un frame que muy probablemente no coincide con el del padre.

Intenta algo como esto:

```
LoginTableViewController *contributeViewController = [[LoginTableViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:[UIHelpers blurredViewController:contributeViewController withFrame:self.view.frame andBlurEffectStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight] animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Por otra parte deberías considerar el uso de `AutoLayout` para configurar adecuadamente las medidas relativas de tus vistas sin importar el tamaño del dispositivo.

Si no funciona, te recomiendo que extiendas más tu pregunta con algún ejemplo de código más completo.

Comment: si te das cuenta, en la pregunta hice una aclaración en la que no use el metodo de UIHelpers sino directamente asi: 
`[self presentViewController:contributeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];`
pero igual no funciona.

Comment: Pero es el mismo caso, estás pasando un controlador con su propia vista, pero cuyas medias pueden ser diferentes a las del padre; sobre todo si trabajaste con `Interface Builder` para un dispositivo (digamos iPhone 6), pero al hacer pruebas estás compilando y corriendo la aplicación para uno diferente (p.e. iPhone 5s, o iPhone 6s Plus). En resumen, el problema es el frame de tu vista y creo que lo podrías resolver, o utilizando `Autolayout` o asignando las nuevas medidas con algo como: `contributeViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height);`